# CSS animation not being applied to div

Tags: css, css-animations

Looking at [Animista.net](http://animista.net/) I would like to write some custom CSS animations. So I thought I would try by using one of their examples, and then tweaking it for my personal use.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
 -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s steps(80, end) both;
 -moz-animation: fade-in 1.2s steps(80, end) both;
 animation: fade-in 1.2s steps(80, end) both;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

But I cannot get the animations to work at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are. You must add animation.

```
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dkarasiewicz/pen/pedBNm)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to define the `@keyframes` to make the animation work. See the attached snippet.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
 -webkit-animation: fade-in 1.2s steps(80, end) both;
 -moz-animation: fade-in 1.2s steps(80, end) both;
 animation: fade-in 1.2s steps(80, end) both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in { 
  from { 
    opacity: 0; 
  } 
  to { 
    opacity: 1.0; 
  }  
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in { 
  from { 
    opacity: 0; 
  } 
  to { 
    opacity: 1.0; 
  }  
}
 @-o-keyframes fade-in { 
  from { 
    opacity: 0; 
  } 
  to { 
    opacity: 1.0; 
  }  
}
@keyframes fade-in { 
  from { 
    opacity: 0; 
  } 
  to { 
    opacity: 1.0; 
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```